# Cannot get WebRTCDemo project anymore?

Tags: android, webrtc

My team has a project which uses video call on Android device. Someone recommended me to have a look for WebRTC and told me that it has an example WebRTCDemo which can show me how to use it.
He gave me a built WebRTCDemo project. I checked it and found that our project can do the same thing just like WebRTCDemo with some modification, which is to use our own transport protocol over WebRTC's video engine and voice engine.
WebRTC's native VIE and VOE support an external transport module to handle the outgoing and incoming RTP packet and the WebRTCDemo uses webrtc::test::channel_transport as the external transport module.

So, my plan is:
- Modify the JNI code of WebRTCDemo
- Use our own transport module and build the WebRTCDemo and get the xyz.so and use it in our own android APP.

However, when I fetch the source code and follow the guide on http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android, I got 30G+ stuff in my disk but,  there's no WebRTCDemo under webrtc/example at all?

Has this project been removed forever? What can I do?

Comment: A little searching brings me to: https://github.com/openpeer/webrtc/tree/master/webrtc/examples/android/media_demo and the last commit there https://github.com/openpeer/webrtc/commit/855acf72d0ce243cd9a91cf08859115e616e111b hints at breaking changes.